# executing operations in PostGis on several raster

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have to perform `ST_Hillshade` on more than 12 raster. Is there an efficient way to perform one query on all the raster?

The following code is just for one raster:

```
CREATE TABLE Hillshade 
as 
select rid, ST_HillShade(rast,1,'32BF', 300,45,255,1) as shade 
from lndsat1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that all your raster entries will be adjacent, you have to do a ST_Union(rast) first (and remove your rid). Don't do the Union afterwards because that would give artefacts on the stitches. See docs [here](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Union.html)

To export your result, have a look at this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14959/how-to-export-a-postgis-raster-to-png

Comment: But my problem is that the rasters are for the same area and they have the same srid, each raster just has a diffrent date

Comment: I don't understand the problem then. Where are your rasters located? E.g.: Different tables? Different records? Different bands?

Comment: i solved the problem, I thought that each column stands for one raster image, but one row stands for one raster image. So my problem is solved. Thanks!